# I got this error while installing npm on my my angular project folder

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fplugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\faizan\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-12-07T00_42_46_255Z-debug-0.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.

Comment: `npm  cache clear --force` does this solve your question?

Comment: Try first the recomendation from @AlanYu if you continue with the issue try this ` npm config rm proxy` and 
` npm config rm https-proxy` in windows terminal/CMD.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario sounds like you may have a slow internet connection.

I solved my this error like SS

[image]

in the following way:

Try increasing the timeout from 60s to 90s by adding this to your `.npmrc` file:

You need create `.npmrc` file if you do not have it

- C:\Users{username}.npmrc (for Windows)
- ~/.npmrc (for Linux/Mac)

  timeout=60000

And you could also try adding if you have a slow internet connection or want to save bandwidth

```
prefer-offline=true
```

Or you can create/update one in the same directory as the project's `package.json` file as well.